# Hard disk Lost partition, not showing in data recovery

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, partition-recovery

Yesterday, when I was connecting my external hard disk while connecting power switch, I was a bit reckless which caused a spark and strangely next thing I know two of my partitions were gone.

I used a data recovery software named active partition recovery and was able to recover data of one partition which was turned into RAW but the second partition (f)'s space has merged with local disk E (which I can't seem to recover).

When I open E's property windows only its own space is shown as you can see in attached screenshot and its contents are not visible in data recovery software either.

[image]

Comment: First of all, do not attempt recovery using the original system. It is not clear if you are doing so, but I'm just saying it to be clear. Are you asking for a solution that runs specifically on Windows or is temporarily running a Linux live system ok? In the latter case, check out my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271 If this is OK for you I might add it as answer here too.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Recovered the data,copied to another hard and formatted the partition.Now everything's good

Comment: Good! Did you use `testdisk` following the guidance provided in the link I posted?

Comment: I see. Well, actually there was no need to buy such a program since it basically does the same as Testdisk.